# *Edit - JW Player - There was an error retrieving your embed

Tags: video, embed, jwplayer

**I've tried to add pictures, but not enough reputation. Still having the same problem. I'm just trying to get it to show the one video, then after I can get that, I'll be working on having multiple videos in that folder and having a playlist.**

the link should be http://archive.therevealedwordtabernaclemedia.com/archive.php

Ethan JWPlayer and/or MisterNeutron, if you could email me I could give the password for the site. Thanks,
vssr0027@gmail.com

"There was an error retrieving your embed.:
Please double check your hosted URL in your JW Dashboard"
I've used the code for self-hosted, as my video's are stored through Media Serve, with the wowza 25 package.

So through my control panel, I'm working out of /public_html/archive/archive.php    -  I'm uploading video through filezilla, putting videos into /public_html/archive/flash_media.

```
<div align="center"><div id="myElement">Loading the player</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
file: "public_html/archive/flash_media/video.flv",
image: "http://example.com/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
width: 640,
height: 360
    });
</script>
<div id="myElement"></div>
```

I've changed the file: "public_html" line to /archive, /archive/flash_media, the full website url then /public_html, etc. Every combo I could think of.  I uploaded a file named video.flv, just to try and pull something up.

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: Can you provide a link? Usually you won't link to public_html though, as that is not visible anywhere else other than via ftp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>JW6</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jwplayer.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style='margin: 0 auto;'><div id='myElement'>Loading the player...</div></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('myElement').setup({
        file: 'http://example.com/archive/flash_media/video.flv',
        image: 'http://example.com/uploads/myPoster.jpg',
        width: 640,
        height: 360
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The "src" attribute for jwplayer.js must be the actual URL where the three JW Player scripts are sitting (jwplayer.js, jwplayer.html5.js, and jwplayer.flash.swf). I don't know where you have those files, so I'm just showing a relative URL, as if the files were in the same directory as your index.html page.

The "file" attribute needs to be the full URL that points to your FLV file. I don't know where you actually have the file, so I'm just showing an example above. Ditto for the "image" attribute.

And "public_html" is never part of a URL. That's just where your web host wants you to stash your public content. So, if you upload video.flv to public_html/archive/flash_media/, the full URL is then what I'm showing above, http://example.com/archive/flash_media/video.flv

Also, `<div align="center">` is not valid HTML5 - it's a deprecated way of centering content. The centering should be accomplished with CSS. I'm showing it as inline, but it would be better to give that div an ID, and put the CSS into the CSS file for the page.

Finally, an FLV is a Flash file, so it won't be playable on any mobile device, no matter what player script you use. Convert your FLV to an MP4, so everyone can see it. Use Handbrake, with the default settings, plus check "Web optimized." It's a freebie, and very reliable: http://handbrake.fr/

Comment: BTW, I have a demo page with a series of simple examples, each with page code to look at. You might find it helpful - see the pull-down menus at the top of the page: http://misterneutron.com/